# Placing different color balls into distinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you place 4 red balls, 5 blue balls, and 6 yellow balls in 4 distinguishable boxes? (Balls with same color are indistinguishable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If you had only the $4$ red balls, this would be a standard [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the same is true if you had only the $5$ blue balls or only the $6$ yellow balls. Solve each of these three problems separately, and combine the solutions appropriately. Note that the three problems really are independent of one another.

Answer (score 0):

$$(^{4+4-1}C_{4-1}) \times  (^{5+4-1}C_{4-1})\times(^{6+4-1}C_{4-1})=(^{7}C_{3}) \times  (^{8}C_{3})\times(^{9}C_{3})$$